# Is there any way to rephrase select statement so query will run faster

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I make use of a fairly advanced query with lots of calculated data based on a view which has calculated data itself. Creating this query takes a lot of time, which is a problem since the query is used to populate data models for Microsoft powerBI. Everytime I refresh my dashboard, my selected queries refresh, and this one in particular takes A LOT of time in order to refresh.

Is there any way to rewrite the select statement so that refreshing won't take 4-6 business days?

```
select top 10 x.model, count(x.model) as 'aantal gedraaid', 
(select avg(deltasec) from dbo.Testview1 where categorie = 'geen stop' and model = x.model) as 'gemiddelde tijd', 
(select count(model) from dbo.Testview1 where categorie in ('Lange stop', 'korte stop') and model = x.model ) as 'aantal stops',
((select sum(deltasec) from dbo.Testview1 where categorie not in ('setuptijd', 'uitschieter') and model = x.model )/3600) as 'total runtime',
((select sum(deltasec) from dbo.Testview1 where categorie in ('geen stop') and model = x.model )/3600) + (select ((cast((select count(model) from dbo.Testview1 where categorie in ('Lange stop', 'korte stop') and model = x.model) as real))* (select avg(deltasec) from dbo.Testview1 where categorie = 'geen stop' and model = x.model ))/3600)   'tijd geen stop',
((select sum(deltasec) from dbo.Testview1 where categorie in ('Lange stop', 'korte stop') and model = x.model )/3600) - (select ((cast((select count(model) from dbo.Testview1 where categorie in ('Lange stop', 'korte stop') and model = x.model) as real))* (select avg(deltasec) from dbo.Testview1 where categorie = 'geen stop' and model = x.model ))/3600) 'tijd stop',
((select sum(deltasec) from dbo.Testview1 where categorie in ('setuptijd') and model = x.model )/3600) as 'setuptijd',
(select min(deltasec) from dbo.testview1 where categorie = 'geen stop' and model = x.model) as 'beste tijd'
from dbo.Testview1 x 
where actie_id = 48 and model <> 'UFO'
group by model
order by max(x.datum) desc
```

EDIT a quick draft of the design of the testview1 view

```
48  nieuw PCB   2019-08-29  14:40:08.7700000    UFO 201908291440    00:00:05.8600000    5,86    uitschieter
48  nieuw PCB   2019-08-29  14:40:02.9100000    UFO 201908291440    00:00:32.4730000    32,47333    geen stop
48  nieuw PCB   2019-08-29  14:39:30.4370000    UFO 201908291439    00:01:31.0300000    91,03001    korte stop
48  nieuw PCB   2019-08-29  14:37:59.4070000    UFO 201908291438    02:00:01.0770000    7201,077    Lange stop
48  nieuw PCB   2019-08-29  12:37:58.3300000    UFO 201908291238    00:00:14.2070000    14,20667    geen stop
48  nieuw PCB   2019-08-29  12:37:44.1230000    UFO 201908291237    00:13:27.4100000    807,41  Lange stop
48  nieuw PCB   2019-08-29  12:24:16.7130000    UFO 201908291224    00:00:26.1670000    26,16667    geen stop
48  nieuw PCB   2019-08-29  12:23:50.5470000    UFO 201908291224    00:00:25.1270000    25,12667    geen stop
48  nieuw PCB   2019-08-29  12:23:25.4200000    UFO 201908291223    00:00:26.4100000    26,41   geen stop
48  nieuw PCB   2019-08-29  12:22:59.0100000    UFO 201908291223    00:00:25.5400000    25,54   geen stop
48  nieuw PCB   2019-08-29  12:22:33.4700000    UFO 201908291222    00:00:25.0600000    25,06   geen stop
48  nieuw PCB   2019-08-29  12:22:08.4100000    UFO 201908291222    00:00:24.7230000    24,72334    geen stop
48  nieuw PCB   2019-08-29  12:21:43.6870000    UFO 201908291221    00:01:24.6670000    84,66667    korte stop
```

Query to select this view

```
select x.*, 
case
    when datum <> lead(datum) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) then 'uitschieter'
    when lead(actie_id) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) = 36 and (lead(custom1) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) like 'Start%' or lead(custom1) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) like 'begin%') then 'setuptijd'
    when lead(actie_id,2) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) = 36 and (lead(custom1,2) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) like 'Start%' or lead(custom1,2) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) like 'begin%') then 'setuptijd'
    when lead(actie_id,3) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) = 36 and (lead(custom1,3) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) like 'Start%' or lead(custom1,3) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) like 'begin%') then 'setuptijd'
    when lead(actie_id,4) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) = 36 and (lead(custom1,4) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) like 'Start%' or lead(custom1,4) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) like 'begin%') then 'setuptijd'
    when lead(actie_id,5) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) = 36 and (lead(custom1,5) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) like 'Start%' or lead(custom1,5) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) like 'begin%') then 'setuptijd'
    when actie_id = 36 then 'uitschieter'
    When deltasec > 200 then 'Lange stop'
    When deltasec <200 and deltasec >60 then 'korte stop'
    When deltasec < 60 and deltasec > 10 then 'geen stop'
    else 'uitschieter'
    end as [Categorie]
from 
(select T_event.Actie_ID, 
case 
    when actie_omschrijving = 'foto' then 'nieuw PCB'
    when actie_omschrijving = 'is leeg' then 'start/stop model'
end as omschrijving,
cast(event_timestamp as date) as datum, cast(event_timestamp as time) as tijd, 
case 
    when left(custom1,4) like '201_%' then 'UFO'
    when t_event.Actie_ID = 48 then left(custom1,4)
    when t_event.Actie_ID = 36 then 'start/stop'
end as model,
custom1, 
cast(T_event.event_timestamp - Lag(T_event.event_timestamp) over (order by T_event.Event_ID) AS time) [Delta],
cast(T_event.event_timestamp - Lag(T_event.event_timestamp) over (order by T_event.Event_ID) AS real) * 86400 as deltasec
from T_event
  inner join T_Actie ON T_event.Actie_ID = T_Actie.Actie_ID
WHERE T_EVENT.Actie_ID in (36,34,48) and t_event.custom1 not like 'einde%'
  and Event_Timestamp >= '2019-07-22') x
```

original T_Event dataset

Additional info:
 This is data represents a manufacturing plant. An event with corresponding timestamp is logged whenever a product enters the final phase of manufacturing. My employer wants me to analyse and visually present this data in a dashboard

```
83  28  2   2012-05-08 08:31:06.843 038200000168    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
84  28  2   2012-05-08 08:31:08.063 038200000170    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
85  28  2   2012-05-08 08:51:27.437 038200000164    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
86  28  2   2012-05-08 08:51:29.250 038200000166    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
87  28  2   2012-05-08 08:52:58.530 038200000160    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
88  28  2   2012-05-08 08:52:59.953 038200000162    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
89  28  2   2012-05-08 08:53:42.483 038200000152    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
90  28  2   2012-05-08 08:53:43.703 038200000154    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
91  28  2   2012-05-08 08:54:24.280 038200000156    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
92  28  2   2012-05-08 08:54:25.750 038200000158    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
93  28  2   2012-05-08 09:02:54.720 038200000148    NULL    NULL    NULL    NULL
```

Comment: It's not as easy as you think. We'd need to know what base tables are actually behind that 'Testview1'. Blindly trying to rewrite your query has low chances of getting to a good solution. For more helpful information, please share your execution plan. For that, please use [PasteThePlan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/)

Comment: are all those subqueries really necessary or could you use conditional aggregation?

Comment: How many rows are there when you query your `Testview1` view?  If you could push the results from the view into a permanent table (`SELECT * INTO dbo.materialised_Testview1 FROM dbo.Testview1`), then add indexes, then run your query, then drop the table, then it would possibly be a lot faster.  But you might not be able to do this for a number of reasons I guess?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu Sadly, i don't have permission to generate the XML plan.

Comment: Have you considered adding this select statement to a [Table Function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-function-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017)?

Comment: explore using different aggregate conditions https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2654750/multiple-aggregate-functions-in-one-sql-query-from-the-same-table-using-differen/

Comment: @birel Sadly, the administrator has not given me permission to edit or create tables. I've been given permission to edit 3 views, being testview1, testview2, testview3.

Additional info
This is data represents a manufacturing plant. A timestamp is logged whenever a product enters the final phase of manufacturing. My employer wants me to analyse and visually present this data in a dashboard.

Comment: Understood @AnthonyLemaire, but remember, a Table Function, is not a physical table, it just returns the data in your select statement as a table - similar to a view, but quicker...

Comment: @Birel Aha, sorry i didn't catch that, i'll look into it

Answer (score 0):

So my suggestion is the following:

```
if exists(select 1 from sysobjects where name = 'fn_SelectQuery_AL')
drop function fn_SelectQuery_AL;

set ansi_nulls on
go

set quoted_identifier on
go

create function fn_SelectQuery_AL()
returns table
with encryption
as
return
(
select x.*, 
case
    when datum <> lead(datum) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) then 'uitschieter'
    when lead(actie_id) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) = 36 and (lead(custom1) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) like 'Start%' or lead(custom1) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) like 'begin%') then 'setuptijd'
    when lead(actie_id,2) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) = 36 and (lead(custom1,2) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) like 'Start%' or lead(custom1,2) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) like 'begin%') then 'setuptijd'
    when lead(actie_id,3) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) = 36 and (lead(custom1,3) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) like 'Start%' or lead(custom1,3) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) like 'begin%') then 'setuptijd'
    when lead(actie_id,4) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) = 36 and (lead(custom1,4) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) like 'Start%' or lead(custom1,4) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) like 'begin%') then 'setuptijd'
    when lead(actie_id,5) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) = 36 and (lead(custom1,5) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) like 'Start%' or lead(custom1,5) over (order by datum desc, tijd desc) like 'begin%') then 'setuptijd'
    when actie_id = 36 then 'uitschieter'
    When deltasec > 200 then 'Lange stop'
    When deltasec <200 and deltasec >60 then 'korte stop'
    When deltasec < 60 and deltasec > 10 then 'geen stop'
    else 'uitschieter'
    end as [Categorie]
from 
(select T_event.Actie_ID, 
case 
    when actie_omschrijving = 'foto' then 'nieuw PCB'
    when actie_omschrijving = 'is leeg' then 'start/stop model'
end as omschrijving,
cast(event_timestamp as date) as datum, cast(event_timestamp as time) as tijd, 
case 
    when left(custom1,4) like '201_%' then 'UFO'
    when t_event.Actie_ID = 48 then left(custom1,4)
    when t_event.Actie_ID = 36 then 'start/stop'
end as model,
custom1, 
cast(T_event.event_timestamp - Lag(T_event.event_timestamp) over (order by T_event.Event_ID) AS time) [Delta],
cast(T_event.event_timestamp - Lag(T_event.event_timestamp) over (order by T_event.Event_ID) AS real) * 86400 as deltasec
from T_event
  inner join T_Actie ON T_event.Actie_ID = T_Actie.Actie_ID
WHERE T_EVENT.Actie_ID in (36,34,48) and t_event.custom1 not like 'einde%'
  and Event_Timestamp >= '2019-07-22') x
)
```

I think this will suffice?

You can then just run the following:

```
select
*
from    dbo.fn_SelectQuery_AL()
```

Let me know if it works.

Comment: When i execute the first string i get the following error code:

Msg 2812, Level 16, State 62, Line 1
Could not find stored procedure 'fn_SelectQuery_AL'.

Comment: I added an else statement after the initial conditional statement. Seems like i don't have the authorisation to create functions either... 
I'll have a talk with the server admin because my restricted authorisation is really limiting my capacity atm

Comment: @AnthonyLemaire, apologies, I forgot to add `dbo` in front of the function... Check if it works now?

Comment: It fixes the initial error, still, i have no permission to create functions. As soon as it gets granted i will let you know.

Comment: @AnthonyLemaire, holdings thumbs for you! :-)